# Firefox Quantum - user-agent incorrect?

Tags: firefox, user-agent, mozilla, firefox-quantum

My Firefox was just updated to Quantum and looks like user-agent is incorrect. It's now:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; rv:1.8.0.3) Gecko/20060426 Firefox/1.5.0.3

All websites, also mozilla.org, show me "Your browser version is old, please update." But after I first run this version, I was informed that this is latest, new Firefox.

Due to this I cannot do anything and also can't install User-Agent switcher which is worked with previous Firefox version.

How I can restore Firefox?

Comment: [User-Agent switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/) works just fine with Firefox 57. Moreover, your user-agent string looks wrong: maybe leftover from some extension? My FF user-agent in 57 looks correct: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0

Comment: Did you try https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-reset-default-user-agent-firefox ? Do you have any add-ons enabled?

Answer (score 8):

Try going to [about:config](http://about:config) and check if `privacy.resistFingerprinting` is set to `true`.

That setting will spoof the user agent; changing it back to the default of `false` solved this issue for me.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.In my case was setting the version to 52. And last but not least was also preventing to save/restore the window size between sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I have multiple computers and each computer is stuck on a different user/agent when the update occurred. Obviously if you used an add-on, whatever the setting was at update is the one you have been branded with. If you do a full delete and reinstall it should fix it. A real pain, but another option may be to dowload a newer user/agent add-on and try to change it that way.